Text editors or viewers that support arbitrarily large canvas sizes
I have a text file with lines that are a few times longer than the largest monitor I can find. The lines must not be wrapped because there are alignment structures that would broken by line wrapping. (Think of the output of the tree command on a directory with many layers of subdirectories.) It's fine to zoom out to the degree where individual characters are illegible, as I only care about the "visual structure" of the text, yet I'm unable to find a text editor that allows arbitrary zooming.
It suffices if there's a text editor that supports rendering to an arbitrarily large canvas and then taking a screenshot of the canvas. I can then zoom out the picture as I want.
